# ffmpeg is cutting video length incorrectly

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to check the length of the video and to cut video.

I have a video with the lenght of 19.458333 seconds that's why i want to cut it to only have 19 seconds because i don't want the floating point.

I check the video length using below command

```
ffprobe -i "video.avi" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

And I use below command to cut video the video

```
ffmpeg -i  "video.avi" -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:19.000 -c copy out.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i  "video.avi" -ss 00:00:00 -t 19 -c copy output.avi
```

The problem i have is when i cut the video with the above command and check the length the output file's length is 19.018 seconds. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Videos length is calculated by frames and its time base. You can't just specify a length and get what you want.

Comment: @halfelf does that mean i need to get the length of a video with a specified frame per seconds?

Answer (score -1):

If your video is 30 frames per second, that means each frame is 1/30 or 0.0333 seconds per frame. So .018 is less than one frames duration.

Comment: Yeah. thats why i want to remove the microseconds. Thats why i wanted to cut the video from 0 to 19th seconds.

Comment: If you cut one more frame, the duration would just be 18.98. Seconds is an arbitrary timebase.

Comment: In short i can't remove the remaining microseconds of the video?

Comment: short answer no. Long answer: maybe with a lot of code, but if the stream has audio as well as video it would depend on the codec, and most likely impossible.